# Is there a better way to write this pivot function in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I've written a function to "pivot" some data tables but wonder if there's a simpler way to accomplish the same result.

```clj
(defn pivot-ab-ba
  [data]
  (r/reduce
   (fn [result [ks c]]
     (assoc-in result ks c))
   {}
   ;; pivot {a [b1 c1 b2 c2]} => [[b1 a] c1] [[b2 a] c2]
   (mapcat (fn [[a bcseq]]
             ;; pivot [a [b c]] => [[[b a] c]]
             (mapcat (fn [[b c]] [[[b a] c]]) bcseq))
           data)))

(let [data {1 {:good [1 2] :bad [3 4]}
            2 {:good [5 6] :bad [7 8]}}]
  (pivot-ab-ba data))

; => {:good {1 [1 2], 2 [5 6]}, :bad {1 [3 4], 2 [7 8]}}
```

This works, but seems over-complicated.

UPDATE:

@TaylorWood proposed a solution below; here is that answer with a modification to avoid passing in the keys that are being pivoted:

```
(defn pivot [data]
  (reduce-kv
    (fn [acc k v]
      (reduce (fn [acc' k'] (assoc-in acc' [k' k] (k' v)))
              acc
              (keys v)))
    {}
    data))
```

UPDATE 2: Thank you all for your answers. Because there is such a diversity of answers I profiled the results to get an idea about how they performed. Admittedly, this is a single test, but still interesting:

```
Benchmarks performed with (criterium.core/bench pivot-function)

# Original pivot-ab-ba
Evaluation count : 8466240 in 60 samples of 141104 calls.
Execution time mean : 7.274613 µs
Execution time std-deviation : 108.681498 ns

# @TaylorWood - pivot
Evaluation count : 39848280 in 60 samples of 664138 calls.
Execution time mean : 1.568971 µs
Execution time std-deviation : 32.567822 ns

# @AlanThompson - reorder-tree
Evaluation count : 25999260 in 60 samples of 433321 calls.
Execution time mean : 2.385929 µs
Execution time std-deviation : 33.130731 ns

# @AlanThompson reorder-tree-reduce
Evaluation count : 14507820 in 60 samples of 241797 calls.
Execution time mean : 4.249135 µs
Execution time std-deviation : 89.933197 ns

# @amalloy - pivot
Evaluation count : 12721980 in 60 samples of 212033 calls.
Execution time mean : 5.087314 µs
Execution time std-deviation : 226.242206 ns
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another way to do it:

```
(defn pivot [data ks]
  (reduce-kv
    (fn [acc k v]
      (reduce (fn [acc' k'] (assoc-in acc' [k' k] (k' v)))
              acc
              ks))
    {}
    data))
```

This takes a map and the expected keys, then reduces over each key/value pair in `data`, then does another inner reduce over each expected key, grabbing their value from the `data` map and assoc'ing it into the output map.

```
(def data
  {1 {:good [1 2] :bad [3 4]}
   2 {:good [5 6] :bad [7 8]}})

user=> (pivot data [:good :bad])
{:good {1 [1 2], 2 [5 6]}, :bad {1 [3 4], 2 [7 8]}}
```

Comment: This is great. I changed the solution to avoid having to pass in the desired keys as a parameter by switching `ks` for `(keys v)` and it's good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it.  I'm using an `atom` to accumulate the results, but you could translate that to `reduce` if you really wanted:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.core tupelo.test) )

(defn reorder-tree
  [data]
  (let [result (atom {})]
    (doseq [[letter gb-data] data]
      (doseq [[gb-key nums-data] gb-data]
        (swap! result assoc-in [gb-key letter] nums-data)))
    @result))

(dotest
  (let [data     {:a {:good [1 2]
                      :bad  [3 4]}
                  :b {:good [5 6]
                      :bad  [7 8]}}

        expected {:good {:a [1 2]
                         :b [5 6]}
                  :bad  {:a [3 4]
                         :b [7 8]}}]

    (is= expected (reorder-tree data))))
```

---

**Update:**   OK, I couldn't resist writing the `reduce` version using a nested `for`:

```
(defn reorder-tree-reduce
  [data]
  (reduce
    (fn [cum-map [letter gb-key nums-data]]
      (assoc-in cum-map [gb-key letter] nums-data))
    {}
    (for [[letter gb-data] data
          [gb-key nums-data] gb-data]
      [letter gb-key nums-data])))
```

Comment: `(doseq [x xs] (doseq [y ys] ...))` can (and IMO always should) be replaced with `(doseq [x xs, y ys] ...)`, just as you do with `for`.

Answer (score 0):

Reduce is an unnecessarily low-level function to accomplish this goal. I'd prefer to generate a sequence of maps, in a way that is self-evidently correct, and then use `merge` to combine them. Interleaving the combination logic with the production logic makes it harder for a reader of the function to see what it's doing and whether it's correct. Relying instead on well-understood, simple functions `merge` and `merge-with` means there's no extra complexity that has to be understood anew.

```
(defn pivot [coll]
  (apply merge-with merge
         (for [[a m] coll
               [b x] m]
           {b {a x}})))
```